# Upload files with Express.js and express-fileupload

Tags: node.js, express, ftp

I'm triying to upload a file to a FTP. I'm using Express.js, Node, and i've found a very nice tutorial on this blog:

https://attacomsian.com/blog/uploading-files-nodejs-express

SO, everything looks fine, but where can i put the config data to FTP (user, host, password...)?

As i understand, express-fileupload is a middleware, so, i need to do an extra step? Or where i have to pass my credentials to make the conection to the FTP?

Next, the code on the blog example:

```
const express = require('express');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const _ = require('lodash');

const app = express();

// enable files upload
app.use(fileUpload({
    createParentPath: true
}));

//add other middleware
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.post('/upload-avatar', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        if(!req.files) {
            res.send({
                status: false,
                message: 'No file uploaded'
            });
        } else {
            //Use the name of the input field (i.e. "avatar") to retrieve the uploaded file
            let avatar = req.files.avatar;

            //Use the mv() method to place the file in upload directory (i.e. "uploads")
            avatar.mv('./uploads/' + avatar.name);

            //send response
            res.send({
                status: true,
                message: 'File is uploaded',
                data: {
                    name: avatar.name,
                    mimetype: avatar.mimetype,
                    size: avatar.size
                }
            });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    }
});

//start app 
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => 
  console.log(`App is listening on port ${port}.`)
);
```

Hope you can help me. Maybe is to easy, but at this hour, my brain is not working anymore.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: express-fileupload is middleware for Express for handling the task of HTTP file upload. It's not an FTP client nor an FTP server. Auth is handled by Express and it outside the scope of express-fileupload's purpose.

Comment: OK, thanks. So, I'm going to need another library to make the connection, right? And then I can use express-fileupload